# Whats is Production enviroment in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am curious to know what the `APP_ENV` entry is used for in Laravel environment files. Is it just for my own usage so I can detect it in code? If I create a fresh Laravel app and change `APP_ENV` to production what will it change under the hood? Nothing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Thanks, but I already read those. What I don't understand is how to configure different .env settings for production and local if there is only one .env file? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Typically you would have a different .env file on each server.

Comment: Ok, so APP_ENV just indicates what the current .env file is used for? It does not change anything in Laravel under the hood, right?

Comment: It is up to you if you would like different parts of your app to work differently in different environments. `.env` file is usually used so that your code can just grab values with the `env` helper function. This way when you change environments like switching from a test API key to a live API key for example, you can just edit the .env file and not touch the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Post it as an answer so I can accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would have a different .env file on each server. It is up to you if you would like different parts of your app to work differently in different environments. The `.env` file is usually used so that your code can just grab values with the env helper function. This way when you change environments like switching from a test API key to a live API key for example, you can just edit the .env file and not touch the rest of your code.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration